# How to sort content of a csv file in java

Tags: java, csv, sorting

I have a big csv file that looks like this

```
 Order ID,Order Priority,Order Quantity,Unit Price,Ship Mode,Customer Name,Customer Segment,Product Category
 3,Low,6,38.94,Regular Air,Muhammed MacIntyre,Small Business,Office Supplies
 293,High,49,208.16,Delivery Truck,Barry French,Consumer,Office Supplies
 293,High,27,8.69,Regular Air,Barry French,Consumer,Office Supplies
 483,High,30,195.99,Regular Air,Clay Rozendal,Corporate,Technology
```

I am able to display it but i don't know how to sort it and display it again sorted. Here's my code so far

```
package project1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice=0;
            boolean flag = true;

            while (flag) {
                System.out.println("Enter 1 to display data.");
                System.out.println("Enter 2 to sort data.");
                System.out.println("Enter 3 to idk.");
                System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit.");
                System.out.print("Your choice: ");
                choice = input.nextInt(); 
                if (choice ==1) {
                    File inputFile = new File("dataToLoad.csv");
                    String line;
                    String delimiter = ",";
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
                    int numberOfLines = 0;
                    int numberOfColumns = 0;
                    while (in.hasNextLine()){
                        line = in.nextLine();
                        numberOfLines++;
                    }
                    in.close();
                    String[][] data = new String[numberOfLines][8];
                    in = new Scanner(inputFile);
                    int currentRow = 0;
                    while (in.hasNextLine()){
                        line = in.nextLine();
                        String[] parts = line.split(delimiter);
                        numberOfColumns = parts.length;
                        for (int i = 0; i<numberOfColumns; i++) {
                            data[currentRow][i] = parts[i];
                        }
                        currentRow++;
                    }
                    in.close();
                    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));
                    for (int row=0; row<numberOfLines; row++) {
                        for (int col=0; col<numberOfColumns; col++) {
                            System.out.printf("%-20s", data[row][col]);
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (choice ==2) {

                    }
                    else 
                        if (choice==0) {
                        System.out.println("Good bye!");
                        flag = false;
                    }
                else System.out.println("I am sorry, this is not a valid option. Please try again.");
            }
            }
    }
}
```

As you can see, i give the user the option to display the data, display them sorted (according to id) and i also want the user to choose how to sort the code. I am stuck at sorting.

Comment: Is this a school project or an actual application? Why are you writing your own CSV parsing?

Comment: Here is a way to do what you want :

- Convert your line in POJO.
- Sort all your POJOs.
- Generate the new csv from sorted POJOs.

Comment: On which parameter do you want to sort the csv file i.e. sort on the basis of order ID, order Priority etc.

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop reinventing the wheel; use a csv open source library (for example, opencsv).
2. Create a class that represents one row of data in your csv file; I'll refer to this as `RowClass`.
3. Read the CSV file one row at a time.  Each row will arrive as a `String[]`.
4. Create and populate one instance of `RowClass` per row of the CSV file.
5. Store the `RowClass` objects in a `List`; I'll call this `rowList`.
6. Sort `rowList` using a `Comparator` that you create.  Create one `Comparator` for each sort option.
7. Implement `RowClass.toString()` to display one row.

Answer (score 0):

This should help, I believe that you will figure out what's going on here

**Main.java**

```
package pkg;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static pkg.Order.OrderBuilder;

public class Main {

    private static Order[] orders = new Order[3];
    private static OrderBuilder orderBuilder = new OrderBuilder();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Order order1 = orderBuilder.createNewOrder().withId(10).withCustomerName("John").withPrice(1.23f).withPriority("high").build();
        Order order2 = orderBuilder.createNewOrder().withId(20).withCustomerName("Lee").withQuantity(3.4f).build();
        Order order3 = orderBuilder.createNewOrder().withId(30).withCustomerName("Someone").withPriority("low").build();

        orders[0] = order3;
        orders[1] = order1;
        orders[2] = order2;

        System.out.println("Before sorting");
        for(int i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(orders[i].getId());
        }

        Arrays.sort(orders);

        System.out.println("After sorting");
        for(int i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(orders[i].getId());
        }
    }
}
```

**Order.java**

```
package pkg;

public class Order implements Comparable<Order> {
    private int id;
    private String priority;
    private float quantity;
    private float price;
    private String shipMode;
    private String customerName;
    private String customerSegment;
    private String productCategory;

    private void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    private void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    private void setQuantity(float quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    private void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    private void setShipMode(String shipMode) {
        this.shipMode = shipMode;
    }

    private void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    private void setCustomerSegment(String customerSegment) {
        this.customerSegment = customerSegment;
    }

    private void setProductCategory(String productCategory) {
        this.productCategory = productCategory;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Order o) {
        return this.id - o.getId();
    }

    static class OrderBuilder {
        private Order order;

        OrderBuilder withId(int id) {
            order.setId(id);
            return this;
        }

        OrderBuilder withPriority(String priority) {
            order.setPriority(priority);
            return this;
        }

        OrderBuilder withQuantity(float quantity) {
            order.setQuantity(quantity);
            return this;
        }

        OrderBuilder withPrice(float price) {
            order.setPrice(price);
            return this;
        }

        OrderBuilder withShipMode(String shipMode) {
            order.setShipMode(shipMode);
            return this;
        }

        OrderBuilder withCustomerName(String customerName) {
            order.setCustomerName(customerName);
            return this;
        }

        OrderBuilder withCustomerSegment(String customerSegment) {
            order.setCustomerSegment(customerSegment);
            return this;
        }

        OrderBuilder withProductCategory(String productCategory) {
            order.setProductCategory(productCategory);
            return this;
        }

        OrderBuilder createNewOrder() {
            order = new Order();
            return this;
        }

        Order build() {
            return order;
        }

    }
}
```